# Moving Average Method

Tags: time-series, self-study, moving-average

Suppose I have data for 6 months: $2,5,1,9,3,4$. If I calculate 3 months moving average, then from this data, I get two average $2.667(=\frac{2+5+1}{3})$ and $5.333(=\frac{9+3+4}{3})$.

But if I have data for only 5 months, $2,5,1,9,3$, and I want to calculate moving average, how can I calculate it?

Comment: Missing values can be ignored, or you can decide that the average is not defined if any value is missing. Your choice.

Comment: @NickCox Suppose I have data for 7 days. No value is missing. Can I calculate moving average in this situation?

Comment: Why not? Length of window is your choice. Odd numbers of values are convenient window lengths, because then the average of $y_{t-k}, \dots, y_{t+k}$ can be regarded as defined for position $t$.

Comment: @NickCox I am struggling to visualize it. Could you please give me a reference, or give an example?

Comment: Chatfield's book on time series should serve. Many older texts and reviews remain valid e.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0065268708604872

Comment: Your examples are not a "moving average": they are *block* averages.  The moving average for your six-number sequence is $8/3, 15/3, 13/3, 16/3.$  The moving average for the truncated five-number sequence omits the last.  So: which form of average are you trying to ask about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We generally do moving average in the following way:

[image]

It means we have to keep on adding 3 months data and move our data point one by one, it means for this data 2,5,1,9,3,4:

Moving avg1=(2+5+1)/3

Moving avg2=(5+1+9)/3

Moving avg3=(1+9+3)/3

For even moving averages you have to iterate one more times for odd moving average you have to do single iteration.